# File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system in Angular 6 (pdfMake)

Tags: angular, typescript, pdfmake

I`m getting

> ERROR Error: File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file
>   system

when trying using pdfMake in angular 6.

I did

```
declare module 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
declare module 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';`
```

in typings.d.ts and also

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "../src/typings.d.ts"
],
```

in tsconfig.json.

In component where i`m using pdfmake i have

```
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
```

Seems like vfs_fonts.js loading because i added console.log to this file and it works.

Also i tryed just to add

```
<script src="./assets/fonts/vfs.js"></script>
```

But still getting the same error. 
Maybe someone got a solution for this?

UPD 1:
Importing pdfmake.js before not solved a problem

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
```

SOLUTION:

```
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
```

and

```
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

SOLVED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ts file

import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";

constructor(){
    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `vfs` is readonly. Are you using typescript? how did you solve this?

Comment: @GilEpshtain use `( <any> pdfMake ).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs`

Answer (score 4):

Install the scripts using NPM:

```
npm i -S pdfmake
npm i -D @types/pdfmake
```

In your Angular component/ service:

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

// ...

public downloadPdf(): void
{
  const pdfData: TDocumentDefinitions = {
    content: [
      'First paragraph'
    ]
  };

  const pdfFile = pdfMake.createPdf(pdfData, null, null, pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs);

  pdfFile.download();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 9-10,
open up angular.json
add the following under both scripts sections...
"./node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js",
"./node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the steps below from :
[pdfMake site](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/vfs/)

I had to do this steps:

- Go to package directory ./node_modules/pdfmake/
- Create the examples/fonts subdirectory in your pdfmake code directory, if it doesn’t already exist.
- Copy your fonts (and other files you wish to embed) into the examples/fonts subdirectory.
- Run command **node build-vfs.js "./examples/fonts"**. Or run node build-vfs.js to show help.
- Include your new build/vfs_fonts.js file in your code (in the same way you include pdfmake.js or pdfmake.min.js).